# Grabbing unnamed(?) data from json with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm having a bit of trouble here...

I'm trying to grab some values from a json file [here,](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/weaponsPopulateStats/250430234/1/) and it can be formatted [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

The json file looks like this:

```
{
"type": "success",
"message": "OK",
"data": {
"mainWeaponStats": [
{
"category": "Machine guns",
"timeEquipped": 3507,
"startedWith": null,
"code": "mgRPK",
"headshots": 18,
"name": "RPK",
"kills": 100,
"deaths": null,
},
{
"category": "Handheld weapons",
"timeEquipped": 5452,
"startedWith": null,
"code": "wahUGL",
"headshots": 1,
"name": "Underslung Launcher",
"kills": 108,
"deaths": null,
},
{
"category": "Sniper rifles",
"timeEquipped": 307,
"startedWith": null,
"code": "srMK11",
"headshots": 0,
"name": "MK11",
"kills": 2,
"deaths": null,
},
```

And so on.

I want to grab the kills of one of these items. Meaning I want to give a parameter like "Underslung Launcher" and return with 108.
In this case, the "Underslung Launcher".
I'm looking for a code like this:

```
$gamemode = $decode['data']['topStats']['mapMode'];
```

But if anyone know a better way, please, tell me.
Since the items in the list doesn't have a "name", unlike "data" & "mainWeaponStats", I can't really figure out how to do this.

Edit:
This is the relevant code so far:

```
$weaponstats = "http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/weaponsPopulateStats/" . $bf3id . "/1/";
$content = file_get_contents($weaponstats);
$decode = json_decode($content, true);

$mainweaponstats = $decode['data']['mainWeaponStats'];
```

As you can see, I'm having a hard time learning Json.
I'm trying to read up on it, but as of now, I can't figure this out.

I don't really know how I'm going to do it, as the values I'm trying to find are within the same group.

Comment: if i understood right you want to give a parameter like Underslung Launcher and return 108?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `mainWeaponStats` is an array.  Loop through, and check each one to see if its name matches, then return the kills.

Comment: Could you provide me with a code? I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: @MatsBakken Can you show what you have tried so far? If we just *give* you the code it won't help you learn how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mainweaponstats = $decode['data']['mainWeaponStats'];
```

This is an array of objects (well arrays because you passed `,true` to `json_decode`).  Just loop through this and find what you want.

```
$search = 'Underslung Launcher';
$kills = 0;
foreach($mainweaponstats as $w){
    if($w['name'] === $search){
        $kills = $w['kills'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $kills;
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I can continue with my project now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?

$name = "Underslung Launcher";

$json = file_get_contents("json.php");
$dec = array();
$dec = json_decode($json,true);

$datas = $dec['data']['mainWeaponStats'];

foreach($datas as $data)
{
    if($data['name']==$name) {
        echo $data['kills'];
        break;
    }
}
?>
```